# Кириллица в django HttpResponse

Tags: python, django

Хочу вывести сообщение кириллицей. Файл `views.py` сохранён в кодировке `utf-8` без `BOM`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
""" код """
def CreateReport(request):
    return HttpResponse(u'Проверьте введённые данные: ошибка ввода', content_type = 'text/plain')
```

Вроде бы всё прописано верно, но результатом является строка:

> "РџСЂРѕРІРµСЂСЊС‚Рµ РІРІРµРґС‘РЅРЅС‹Рµ РґР°РЅРЅС‹Рµ: РѕС€РёР±РєР° РІРІРѕРґР°"

Как вывести её всё-таки кириллицей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внезапно всё получилось. Правильная строка HttpResponse выглядит так:

```
return HttpResponse(u'Проверьте введённые данные: ошибка ввода')
```

Хотя до этого такой синтаксис выводил ошибку.